# get the max of a RDD for each key and each dimension

Tags: scala, apache-spark, max

I have a RDD like this one :

```
RDD[(Vector, Int)] : 
example : [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.21052631578947367,0.7894736842105263,0.0,0.0],97
```

and what I would like to get is the max for each key (here the key is 97 for instance) and for each dimension for my vector

What I mean by dimension is this :

```
[0.0 , 0.0 , 0.0 , 0.0 , 0.21052631578947367 , 0.7894736842105263 , 0.0 , 0.0]
  ^     ^     ^     ^         ^                       ^              ^     ^
Dim1 , Dim2 ,Dim3, Dim4,      Dim5           ,        Dim6        , Dim7 , Dim8
```

So basically I would like to get the max for each key and each dimension1 dimension2 ...) between all the RDD

In fact I am trying to get this using numDimension as a parameter, but I cannot use it this way :

```
 def getMaxValue(data: RDD[DBSCANLabeledPoint], numDimension:Int) : RDD[(Int)] = {
   data.map(p =>  (p.${numDimension},p.cluster)).reduceByKey(math.max(_, _))
  }
```

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: what do you mean by dimension?

Comment: for instance in my example `[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.21052631578947367,0.7894736842105263,0.0,0.0]` is of dimension 8 (number of double between commas), so I would like to get the max for each key on the "column 1", max for each key on the "column2" etc... "column 1" being the first double in vector of each RDD

Comment: you can't apply a reduce in your rdd to get the max vector elements ? like this rdd.map(_._1).reduce((v1,v2) => v1.zip(v2).map(v => v._1 max v._2))

Comment: @Mehrez nope it doesn't work, I got code errors and I try to apply reduce or reducebyKey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming we have a `vectors : Rdd[(Vector, Int)]` (that is `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector`), containing many pairs of `(vector[float], Int)` like:

```
[0.1,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.21052631578947367,0.7894736842105263,0.0,0.0],97
[0.0,0.3,0.0,0.0,0.21052631578947367,0.7894736842105263,0.0,0.0],97
[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.21052631578947367,0.7894736842105263,0.0,0.0],99
[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.21052631578947367,0.7894736842105263,0.0,0.0],96
```

here is what I would do:

```
val result : RDD[(Int, Vector)] = vectors
  .map(tuple => (tuple._2, tuple._1))
  .reduceByKey((left, right) =>
    Vectors.dense(
      left.toArray.zip(right.toArray)
       .map(pair => pair._1.max(pair._2)
      )
    )
  )
```

Here is what the code does:

1. **map** - swap the key and the value, so we can use `reduceByKey`
2. **reduceByKey** - reduce all items with the same key using the provided function
3. **The inner function** - This function is provided to the `reduceByKey` method and is used to reduce two elements into a single element. It does two things.  First, the two vectors are zippped into a single vetor of pairs, holding the values from both vectors. Then we apply **map** to that vector, to convert the `Vector[(Float,Float)]` into a `Vector[Float]`. We do this by replacing each pair of `Float`s with the maximum value of the two.
4. **dense** - Since `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector` doesn't support `zip()`, we convert is to a `Array[Float]` for the zip, and then back to a `Vector` when we're done merging the arrays.

So after you run the code above, `result` will have the following values:

```
97,[0.1,0.3,0.0,0.0,0.21052631578947367,0.7894736842105263,0.0,0.0]  
99,[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.21052631578947367,0.7894736842105263,0.0,0.0]  
96,[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.21052631578947367,0.7894736842105263,0.0,0.0]
```

Comment: @LaureD, I wrote this from a mobile device, so the code wasn't 100% correct. I'll update it and add some clarifications.

Comment: Ok I see, that is what I was trying to have eventually ^^ However are you sure I can zip vectors like that ? Because I have an error inside the reduceByKey (using intelliJ) 
Besides I don't really understand the part `map(pair => pair._1.max(pair._2)
    )` because let's suppose zip works, then we would have something like this `[(0.1,0.0),(0.0,0.3),(0.0,0.0),(0.0,0.0),(0.21052631578947367,0.21052631578947367),(0.7894736842105263,0.7894736842105263),(0.0,0.0),(0.0,0.0)]` so where do we iterate over all the couples ?

Comment: @LaureD - yes, zip() is part of Vector's API. I also clarified a little more  about the reduce function.

Comment: I understand what you arte trying to do but where do you see zip() in Vector's API ? I can only apply it to Array[Double] but not to vector, and I checked Spark scala Vector API and I don't see zip()

Comment: Indeed, the `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector` doesn't have `zip()`. So let's update the answer.

Comment: Thank you ! With your previous solution I was using toArray like that but I put the vectors.dense() inside the map(pair => ... ) instead of putting it like you did